# Как найти среднее расстояний между объектами и центроидом отнесенных к кластеру 0

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, кластеризация

Мне необходимо найти среднее расстояний между объектами, отнесенными к кластеру 0, и центроидом этого кластера.
В результате кластеризации получились следующие значения:[image: результат кластеризации]

Так же есть массив расстояний от данных до всех центроидов:

```
array([[ 5.23450093, 16.31035799,  9.08639092],
   [ 4.83735465,  8.48691804,  7.31864058],
   [ 9.33809402,  3.21886799,  5.15388203],
   [13.6821051 ,  3.32080981,  8.09706737],
   [15.64608577,  8.8897569 , 15.47780669],
   [ 0.63245553, 12.00115735,  6.56220237],
   [ 4.5607017 , 15.3306157 ,  8.09706737],
   [ 5.83095189, 11.57703666, 10.68000468],
   [ 7.37563557,  5.13430727,  3.81608438],
   [15.42076522,  3.70060055, 10.25      ],
   [ 7.82304289, 10.10088005,  2.01556444],
   [ 7.72010363,  7.304869  ,  1.03077641],
   [ 8.54400375,  4.90181372,  7.84617741],
   [ 7.33484833, 10.90998523,  2.65753645],
   [15.26433752,  5.54025671,  9.03119593]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас уже есть матрица расстояний до кластерных центроидов - дальше простая работа с матрицами.

Алгоритм решения:

1. выбираем из матрицы расстояний только строки, принадлежащие кластеру `0`
2. считаем среднее значение (функция/метод `mean`) в получившейся на предыдущем шаге матрице в первом столбце (столбец с индексом `0`). Я исхожу из того, что расстояния до кластера `0` находятся в первом столбце матрицы расстояний.

Comment: Спасибо большое!